# this simple function in python doesn't work properly

Tags: python, list

I have some problems with these lines of program. I'm writing a function in python that takes a list of lists and a string as input and returns "the name is here" if the second element of a list in the list of lists is equal to the string given. In this case the list of list I have is this

```
railway = [["Milan","Zurich"],["Zurich","Bern"],["Bern","Berlin"],["Berlin","Copenaghen"]]
```

my function is:

```
def travel( list , stringdestination):
        i = 0
    for elemento in range(len(list)):
      if list[i][1] == stringdestination:
          print "target reached"
```

when I run:

```
travel(railway, "Bern")
```

it should display: "target reached" but it doesn't, it doesn't show anything, why?

Comment: When does `i` get updated?  Try changing that.

Comment: Don't iterate lists like that. Use `for item in list:`.  And don't name your list `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never incrementing i. Your loop should be:

```
for pair in list:
    if pair[1] == stringdestination:
        print "target reached"
```

Comment: never use the name `list` for a list

Comment: Sure, using anything from __builtin__ is a no-no, but they are not reserved keywords. I would also like to see less overlap with commonly used variable names like list and type.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you update you answer to use something like `my_list`, `destination` or similar to serve as a example for good variable naming

Answer (score 3):

As it's been answered, you're not incrementing the loop variable. But that's what's wrong trivially, more importantly, you're coming at this screw like a man with only a hammer in his toolbox. This is pretty much the exact reason the data structure called dictionary was made. It's a built in.

Read up on this, it's much easier and nicer.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: @FEdericoSOmaschini, if you need the data to be ordered, you can use OrderedDict from Collections: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: thanks Kyle I started working with dictionaries but the problem was that data wasn't ordered

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. Don't use `list` as a variable name. `list` is a built in name
2. Iterate lists directly `for i in mylist`
3. It is possible to 'unpack' the pairs in your list by assigning to 2 variables in the iteration

For example:

```
def travel(places, destination):
    for start, dest in places:
        if destination == dest:
            print "target reached"
            break
```

It is likely you want to stop iterating when you find the destination. Do so either by returning immedately from the function or breaking and not returning anything (if no `return` in a function it implicitly returns `None`).

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap it in a `function`, so I stop when a founded the right string. It prevents from looping through the whole list:

```
def arrived(s, raileway):
    for r in railway:
        if r[1] == s:
            return True
    return False

if arrived("Bern", railway):
    print("target reached")
```

Comment: IMHO, the operator module should be avoided. It rarely makes code more readable. I have no idea why 'itemgetter(1)(r)' is more readable than 'r[0]'.